# Python - How to make web scraper run continuously?

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping

I have written a python script to log in a website, collect information and then save it as json in a database (MongoDB)

How can I make it run every 30 minutes or 2 hours?

**Note**: I plan on using Flask when deploying.

Answer (score 1):

If you use linux or unix, you can use crontab,
just:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script
crontab -e
# and then add 
0,30 * * * * /path/to/your/script  # every 30min
# or 0 0-23/2 * * * /path/to/your/script  # every 2 hours
# save out
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`time.sleep(seconds)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) function.

For example this will print `Hey` every 30 minutes:

```
import time
while True:
    print 'Hey'
    time.sleep(1800)
```

*Note: 1800 seconds is 30 minutes*